# Python unittest: Run multiple assertions in a loop without failing at first one, but continue

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, assertions, python-unittest

**Scenario:**
one of my test cases is executing a shell program with a couple of input files and a specific output. I'd like to test different variations of these input/output and each of these variations is saved in its own folder, i.e. folder structure

```
/testA
/testA/inputX
/testA/inputY
/testA/expected.out
/testB
/testB/inputX
/testB/inputY
/testB/expected.out
/testC/
...
```

Here's my code for running this test:

```
def test_folders(self):
    tfolders = glob.iglob(os.environ['testdir'] + '/test_*')                
    for testpath in tfolders:
        testname = os.path.basename(testpath)
        self.assertTrue(self.runTest(testname))
```

testname in this case is "testX". It executes the external program with `inputs` in that folder and compares it to `expected.out` in that same folder.

**Problem:**
As soon as it hits a test that fails, the testing stops and get:

```
Could not find or read expected output file: C:/PROJECTS/active/CMDR-Test/data/test_freeTransactional/expected.out
======================================================================
FAIL: test_folders (cmdr-test.TestValidTypes)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROJECTS\active\CMDR-Test\cmdr-test.py", line 52, in test_folders
    self.assertTrue(self.runTest(testname))
AssertionError: False is not true
```

**Question:**
How do I make it continue the rest of the tests and show how many failed? 
(in essence dynamically create a unittest and execute it)

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need to make a test suite, add tests to it and run, see this relevant thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156782/how-to-add-dozen-of-test-cases-to-a-test-suite-automatically-in-python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
def test_folders(self):
    tfolders = glob.iglob(os.environ['testdir'] + '/test_*')    

    failures = []    
    for testpath in tfolders:
        testname = os.path.basename(testpath)
        if not self.runTest(testname):
            failures.append[testname]

    self.assertEqual([], failures)
```

Comment: this would be awesome if it told me which `testname`(s) failed specifically.

Comment: I've modified the code example. The message should now show the differing elements (failures).

Answer (score 0):

put assert statement in a try block and loop will iterate completely, even if assertion fails:

```
 try:
    assert statement
except
    print("exception occurred!!")
```