# Run unittests from a different file

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a file `TestProtocol.py` that has unittests. I can run that script and get test results for my 30 tests as expected. Now I want to run those tests from another file `tester.py` that is located in the same directory. Inside `tester.py` I tried `import TestProtocol`, but it runs 0 tests.

Then I found the documentation which says I should do something like this:

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover(".", pattern = "*")
unittest.run(suite)
```

This should go through all files in the current directory `.` that match the pattern `*`, so all tests in all files. Unfortunately it again runs 0 tests.

There is a [related QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156782/how-to-add-dozen-of-test-cases-to-a-test-suite-automatically-in-python) that suggests to do

```
import TestProtocol
suite = unittest.findTestCases(TestProtocol)
unittest.run(suite)
```

but that also does not find any tests.

How do I import and run my tests?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try with following

```
# preferred module name would be test_protol as CamelCase convention are used for class name
import TestProtocol

# try to load all testcases from given module, hope your testcases are extending from unittest.TestCase
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(TestProtocol)
# run all tests with verbosity 
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Here is a full example

file 1: test_me.py

```
# file 1: test_me.py 
import unittest

class TestMe(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

file 2: test_other.py, put this under same directory

```
# file 2: test_other.py, put this under same directory
import unittest
import test_me

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(test_me)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

run each file, it will show the same result

```
# python test_me.py - Ran 1 test in 0.000s
# python test_other.py - Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

Comment: Unfortunately that too gives me `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s OK`.

Comment: @nwp I have updated my answer with a working example, hope this would be helpful

Comment: It is working now. The reason it did not work for me before was that I had `unittest.main()` (without `if __name__ == '__main__'`) inside `test_me.py` which prevented the tests from being found.

Comment: @Shaikhul very nice, thank you for sharing.  How would you just receive the status code?

Comment: Late to the party. @Eric you'd just change `verbosity=2` to `verbosity=1` (or another level).