# Creating a Unit testcase Class within a function not running testcases

Tags: python, unit-testing

I need to create a unit test class with a function so i can call the function when some event is triggered. I am using the below method but testcases are not executing

```
gp = r"somefile"

def MyFunc():


if os.path.exists(gp):
    print("yes")

    class First__Test_Cases(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_001(self):
            print("1")


        def test__002(self):
            print("2")


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()

    First__Test_Cases()
else:
    print("fail")
```

MyFunc()

output - Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Comment: What is actually the reason, why you need to create this test class in a function? This looks like a design issue for me. Knowing what is your reason may help others to come up with a more elegant solution

Comment: This absolutely sounds https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ... no matter what problem you intend to solve this way: dont do it.

Comment: Now with your changes in the code, I am honestly more confused (also because of your missing indentation for the function's body)... Just so I understand your intention correctly: you want to run the test cases only if a certain file exists, otherwise, they should fail (or should they be ignored?)

Answer (score 1):

Remove MyFunc() and global parts, it should only contain class and main

mytestfile.py

```
import unittest

class First_Test_Cases(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_001(self):
        Pass

    def test__002(self):
        Pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Then run

```
python mytestfile.py
```

And all tests in the class will be executed:

```
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

You can read more and see more examples in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)

If you need to have a function call the test, you should do that in a separate file. Check this post: [Run unittests from a different file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559473/run-unittests-from-a-different-file)

Comment: Thanks  ...   but this is not i am looking for  as i have mentioned in question i need to place unit test class inside function as i need to call it when some event is triggered

Comment: But then you could take the solution of @Boefst and create a process, that runs the tests when your event is triggered

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood from your change in code, this is your use case:

> Tests should be run only if a certain file exists. Otherwise, they should be skipped.

For this use case, I would suggest the following solution:

```py
import os
import unittest

gp = "some_file.txt"
msg = "file {} does not exist".format(gp)

class First_Test_Cases(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.skipUnless(os.path.exists(gp), msg)
    def test_001(self):
        pass

    @unittest.skipUnless(os.path.exists(gp), msg)
    def test_002(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The output would be the following if the file does not exist:

```sh
ss
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK (skipped=2)
```

and this one, if it exists:

```sh
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

In case if you want your **tests to fail**, just change the code in this way:

```py
import os
import unittest

gp = "some_file.txt"
msg = "file {} does not exist".format(gp)

class First_Test_Cases(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_001(self):
        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(gp), msg) # add this line
        # your code

    def test_002(self):
        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(gp), msg) # add this line
        # your code
```

Then, the output would be the following:

```sh
FF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_001 (__main__.First_Test_Cases)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 11, in test_001
    self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(gp), msg)
AssertionError: file some_file.txt does not exist

======================================================================
FAIL: test_002 (__main__.First_Test_Cases)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 15, in test_002
    self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(gp), msg)
AssertionError: file some_file.txt does not exist

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Comment: Hi Bloody thanks for reply the main point in my question is whole Class should be inside a function & when i call the function the test cases inside class should execute