# How do we develop webdriver or selenium code effectively

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I come from a unit test world but my current project requires me to write a lot of webdriver code. I have to send some applications to some website not having any api. I am using webdriver to go to their website and complete the application. I am facing unique challenge as it takes a lot of time for each run and when I code the the process for nth page of application I wouldn't really be able to test my code very fast. I tend to run the code to test which takes considerable amount of time reducing my efficiency. Am I missing any thing. What is the best practice to develop in such environments. I am using python wto write webdriver.

This is how my code is structured currently.

```
class ApplyPage1():
...
.
.
class ApplyPageN():
```

I cannot reach page N directly as the website I am submitting application to doesn't allow me to go directly to that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at [robotframework-selenium2](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library) as a method of testing web applications and such.  Also look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/830011) for an example on how to use it.  I can also help with more specific questions too if you have any.

The robotframework is extensive but very useful when testing web based stuff.  It's written in python too.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) plugin (with [code formatters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5749321/55075)) for Firefox which has the ability to record the user actions and export the test cases directly into Python 2 `unittest` code (either WebDriver or Remote Control, for Python 3 see [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7517)). See: [Converting IDE scripts to Python](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Converting_IDE_scripts_to_Python) at Mozilla Wiki page.

Once you exported your test into classes, then you can write a wrapper to run all the tests at once. See: [how to to organize python unittests into suites](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759128), [run multiple classes in single Test Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5360833/55075) and [run all Python unit tests in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732438/55075).